# How to merge arrays of complex objects in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following data in my database

```js
db.rows.insertMany([
    {
        _id: 'row1',
        spreadSheetId: 'sheet1',
        data: [
            {
                id: 'field1',
                value: 'value1'
            },
            {
                id: 'field2',
                value: 'value2'
            }
        ]
    }
])
```

Now the user updates the data in the spreadsheet and the following data is sent to the server

```json
{
  "_id": "row1",
  "spreadSheetId": "sheet1",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "field2",
      "value": "value2 updated"
    },
    {
      "id": "field3",
      "value": "value3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to write a MongoDB query that will merge those data arrays into a single one based on their id as a key.
So I want my final row to look like this

```json
{
  "_id": "row1",
  "spreadSheetId": "sheet1",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "field1",
      "value": "value1"
    },
    {
      "id": "field2",
      "value": "value2 updated"
    },
    {
      "id": "field3",
      "value": "value3"
    }
  ]
}
```

One of the approaches I tried was to pull all the data segments from the data array and push the new ones, but Mongo does not allow me to do that in a single query.
Is there any way to do this with a single method?

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to do this using an aggregation pipeline to update my row.
For that, I

- filtered out all the fieldIds that I am updating
- merged the resulting data with my input data
- set my data to the result of that concatenation

Here's the code

```js
let ROW_ID = 'row1';
let MODIFIED_FIELDS = ['field2'];
let NEW_DATA = [
    {
        id: 'field2',
        value: 'value 2 updated'
    },
    {
        id: 'field3',
        value: 'value 3'
    }
]

db.rows.updateOne(
    {
        _id: ROW_ID,
    },
    [
        {
            $set: {
                data: {
                    $concatArrays: [
                        {
                            $filter: {
                                input: "$data",
                                as: "item",
                                cond: {
                                    $not: {
                                        $in: ["$$item.id", MODIFIED_FIELDS],
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        NEW_DATA
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```